# url rewriting not working with proxy_fgci

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I have a local server for development which was created with puphpet. it has php_fpm and proxy_fgci which I don't know what is different between normal apache2 with mod_rewrite

apache modules I have

```
modules:
    - deflate
    - headers
    - proxy_fcgi
    - rewrite
    - proxy
```

this is virtual host setting

```
       directories:
            avd_tutorial:
                provider: directory
                path: /var/www/tutorial.dev
                options:
                    - Indexes
                    - FollowSymlinks
                    - MultiViews
                allow_override:
                    - All
                require:
                    - 'all granted'
                custom_fragment: ''
                files_match:
                    vxrwfpx9uf6y:
                        provider: filesmatch
                        path: \.php$
                        sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                        custom_fragment: ''
```

my htaccess code

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/((.*\.php)(/.*)?)$
 RewriteCond %2 -f
 RewriteRule . fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/%1 [L,P]
 RewriteOptions Inherit

 RewriteRule ^read/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ read.php?PostID=$1 [P,L]
```

url I want is `www.tutorial.dev/read/3`

but when I visit this url I get 404 error.

Comment: did you check it, if you check that please vote it!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found you answer,

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^read/([0-9]+)/?$    read.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

You just change that **[P,L]** to **[NC,L]**

Your link must be look like that: [www.tutorial.dev/read/3](http://#)

Here is the demo: http://test.softbazz.com/danielfew/danielfew/2/

By changing the of [danielfew/{id=number}/](http://#)  it will change

Comment: it's not working. I guess the problem is apache itself.

Comment: @ErdemEce: ok wait i will make for you some thing